# Blocked threads on JDBC4Connection and Log4J

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, blocked-threads

I am facing high CPU utilization issue with tomcat7. A web app developed using JDK7 is deployed on the tomcat server. This web app contacts a MySQL server that is running on a different instance, for CRUD functions.

CPU usage of tomcat becomes abnormally high once in a week. To analyse it, I had taken thread dump and found that are some blocked threads.

Most of the blocked threads have the following stack trace,

> ajp-bio-8009-exec-20604 - priority:10 - threadId:0x0000000001aac000 -
>   nativeId:0x4143 - state:BLOCKED stackTrace: java.lang.Thread.State:
>   BLOCKED (on object monitor) at
>   org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:204)
>   - waiting to lock <0x000000008bf42fc8> (a org.apache.log4j.Logger) at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391) at
>   org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:838) at
>   com.myUtil.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:37) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>   - locked <0x00000000db84e148> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Locked ownable synchronizers:
>   - <0x00000000db84e190> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

And another stack trace related to JDBC connection,

> ajp-bio-8009-exec-20585 - priority:10 - threadId:0x000000000190f000 -
>   nativeId:0x40d6 - state:BLOCKED stackTrace: java.lang.Thread.State:
>   BLOCKED (on object monitor) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.isValid(JDBC4Connection.java:93)
>   - waiting to lock <0x000000008bdf9890> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection) at
>   com.myUtil.dbconnection.DBAccessObject.IsConnected(DBAccessObject.java:751)
>   at
>   com.myUtil.dbhandler.MyDBHandler.InitOrGetConnection(MyDBHandler.java:119)
>   at
>   com.myUtil.dbhandler.MyDBHandler.GetNotification(MyDBHandler.java:8585)
>   at com.myUtil.util.ProcessRequest.myPost(ProcessRequest.java:1539) at
>   com.myUtil.util.ProcessRequest.doPost(ProcessRequest.java:104) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at com.myUtil.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:58) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>   - locked <0x00000000db7c38f8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Locked ownable synchronizers:
>   - <0x00000000db7c3940> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

I checked the status of MySQL server. But everything (No. of connections/threads) was normal there.

This application was working fine for the past 4 years. Only for the past 3 months, I am facing this issue. And no changes were done to the server code. I had to restart the server, every time this issue occurred.

How can I find the root cause of this problem and fix this issue permanently?